# How to fast forward a PIXI spine animation to last frame?

Tags: pixi.js

I am facing problem while playing last frame of pixi spine animation directly.
The animation works fine but i want to skip all frames and run last frame only.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was:

```
trackEntry.trackTime = trackEntry.trackEnd;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Found this more usefull:

```
trackEntry.trackTime = trackEntry.animation.duration
```